# How to File Watch a directory then automatically load to HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I am extremely new to Hadoop and for the past few days have been trying to get a grasp of it all. I've been reading Tom Whites "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" and poking around on various tutorials on HortonWorks. I've also set up a Sandbox on a VM locally to play with.

Basically we will have a directory on a system that files will be dumped to. Whenever a file is placed in this directory, it should be moved/copied remotely into our HDFS.

This sounds like it should be a common use case but I can't seem to find much information regarding something like this. I've briefly looked into Oozie and Falcon since they seem to be workflow tools/management systems. But I can't really find something that does what I want. I would rather use something that is built into Hadoop or commonly configured with it then rolling my own File Watcher or services to do it.

I don't know if I'm asking the wrong questions, looking in the wrong places, or if there is a fundamental flaw in my understanding of hadoop.

Could somebody help point me in the right direction or if I'm misunderstanding something, correct me on how it does works.

EDIT: This [blog post](http://www.pythian.com/blog/hadoop-faq-getting-started-version/) suggests using a Cron job to periodically scan a directory. I don't have experience writing cron jobs but it seems that would presumably just run a File Watching script at a regular interval. I was hoping to find something built into hadoop or at least a tool used almost exclusively with hadoop like Flume or Sqoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this isn't a perfect fit for what I described in the question above but we decided to use Flume. Flume has the Spool Directory type which scans for files on a directory and then puts them into whatever sink you define. I first set it up to just put them into HDFS, but we are now fluming them into HBase using a custom serializer.

We were able to get around the remote fileWatching by just having the files be pushed to our cluster where the Flume agent is. Although I think if we installed a Flume node on the remote computer than we could flume the files from one agent on the remote machine, to the agent on the cluster and it would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use HFDS fuse.

You can mount it on linux based systems and use the regular filewatcher